# Download jar with dependencies using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-dependency-plugin

**I would like to use Maven to download a "fat" jar- one that includes all of its dependencies.** (The same sort of jar that is built using the `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor Ref in the `maven-assembly-plugin`)

The default behavior of `mvn dependency:copy` is to download the jar and all of its dependencies in separate files. *This is not what I want*. I want the dependencies to be included in the jar itself.

How do I achieve this using Maven? If it's not possible, is there some sort of manual way of assembling the fat jar myself given all its dependency JARs?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. You mentioned the `maven-assembly-plugin` which does exactly what you described; it builds a *fat* JAR containing the shaded dependencies.

Comment: @JacobG I need to download a fat jar from a Maven repository, not assemble one.

Comment: So you're saying that, when you download a JAR from Maven Central, it doesn't contain its shaded dependencies?

Comment: @JacobG. I am not using Maven Central; it is an internal company Maven repository. But yes, it does not contain any dependencies. Is that not normal?

Comment: Actually, it seems like you are doing something wrong, because I cannot think of any legitimate use-case for such a fat jar. Can you explain to me what you are trying to achieve?